# Failed to export function properly, es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

So last I checked I was doing everything right, but I need a second set of eyes:

**convert-lock-file.js**

```
import yaml from 'yamljs';

export function convertYarnLockToJSON() {
  yaml.load(__dirname + yarn.lock', (result) => {
      console.log(result); // eslint-disable-line
  });
}
```

**fetching-data.js**

```
import convertYarnLockToJSON from '../lib/convert-lock-file';

// else where in the code:

convertYarnLockToJSON();
```

**Error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _convertLockFile2.default) is not a function
```

When I do: `console.log(convertYarnLockToJSON)` I get `undefined`.

Either I am blind, overly tired or something not right. I am using webpack and babel to compile incase that matters. **Ideas?**

Comment: You need to either `export default convertYarnLockToJSON` on a separate line in `convert-lock-file.js` or `import {convertYarnLockToJSON} from '../lib/convert-lock-file'` specifically in `fetching-data.js`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to export the function as `export default`.

Alternatively, you can:

```
import { convertYarnLockToJSON } from '../lib/convert-lock-file';
```